# How to parallax scroll a layout over another in a Fragment without a Toolbar in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, scrollview, parallax

I am using a `Fragment` in my android app.
This `Fragment` does not have it's own `Toolbar` or `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` element, but rather uses `getSupportActionBar()` from it's parent activity. Now, I want to set up `Parallax Scrolling` of the `ScrollView` over `infoRL`.

I checked some resources online, but most of them are about Parallax a `ScrollView` over an `ImageView`, or use `Toolbar`s in the layout.

So I was wondering how I can go about structuring them.

Here is how my `layout.xml` file is structured.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/infoRL"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/treasur_yellow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_toolbar_element">


    <com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="0dp"
        app:sriv_oval="true"
        app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="0dp" />


    <hunt.ayush.com.traserhunt.utility.CentuaryGothicTextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageBorderLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Fetching Name"
        android:textColor="@color/treasure_black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please try with coordinator layout and collapsable layout inside fragment layout . and then hide toobar.

Comment: I could but thats unnecessary resource usage. I'm trying to find the most optimized may or I'll fall back to that as a backup plan

Comment: create a coordinator layout as top level layout and add appbar layout as first child. Inside that add collapsing toolbar layout and then put your linear layout (which has image) inside that. now you can use collapse mode parallex on imageview. Also put your scrollview as second child of your parent coordinator layout and add layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" as behaviour to scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try with frame layout once

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/heroImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#9E9E9E"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stickyView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#222"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Heading1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```